# How to fetch object using the List Association in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a class A with setters and getters

```
class A{
  private int id;
  private List<B> b;
}
```

I want to fetch the A object based on the B objects. So suppose I have a list of B objects I want to get the A objects that contain the B.
So i decided to use `in`
Here is the code

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class).setCacheable(false); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("b",{list of B})).list();
```

This gives an error `java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1`

How can I get object A using B

Answer (score 0):

You should join the B's first:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class)
   .setCacheable(false)
   .setFetchMode("bList", FetchMode.JOIN)
   .createAlias("bList", "b");
```

and then use an `IN` for the ids of `b`:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("b.id",{list of B})).list();
```

Set your fetch mode accordingly whether you want the list of B's also apart from A.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is giving me an error `could not resolve property: b of: A`

Comment: Is the list annotated with OneToMany / ManyToMany?

Comment: Are you sure the list is named 'b' and has a getter: 'getB()'?

Comment: I think the issue here is, it is not able to find the Alias, b is now an Alias, as per your code

Comment: updated the anser.. you need b.id in the restriction not just b